# org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, transactions

I'm doing a web application for user management system but after processing the login page I have following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction
    

org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:297)
    com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.createCriteria(Unknown Source)
    teste.domain.dao.AbstractDao.createCriteria(AbstractDao.java:16)
    teste.servicos.LoginService.checkLogin(LoginService.java:26)
    teste.web.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:32)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**HibernateUtils.java**

```
package teste.utils;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;


import java.sql.SQLException;

public class HibernateUtils implements Runnable{

    //    private static Session session;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtils.class);
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    static
    {
        try
        {
           createFactory();
        }
        catch (Throwable e)
        {
            logger.fatal(e,e);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    private static void createFactory()
    {
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.configure(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("teste/domain/hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();

    }



    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory()
    {
        if(sessionFactory.isClosed())
           createFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    }



    public static synchronized Session openSession()
    {
//        if(!session.isOpen())
   //      return sessionFactory.openSession();
//        return session;
        return getCurrentSession();
    }
    public static synchronized Session getCurrentSession() throws IllegalStateException
    {
        return getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }


    public static void shutdown() {
        // Close caches and connection pools
        getSessionFactory().close();
    }


    public static void testeSession(){
        Session sess = HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession();
        System.out.println(sess);

    }

    public void run()
    {
        Session sess = getCurrentSession();
        Transaction t2 = sess.beginTransaction();

        t2.begin();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }
        t2.commit();
    }
}
```

**AbstractDao.java**

```
package teste.domain.dao;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import teste.utils.HibernateUtils;

import java.io.Serializable;

public abstract class AbstractDao<CLAZZ>
{

    public abstract Class obtainDomainClass();


    public Criteria createCriteria(){
        return getCurrentSession().createCriteria(obtainDomainClass());
    }

    public Session getCurrentSession()
    {
        return HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession();
    }
    public CLAZZ load(Serializable id)
    {
        return (CLAZZ) HibernateUtils.getaCurrentSession().load(obtainDomainClass(),id);
    }

    public void save(CLAZZ c)
    {
        HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().save(c);
    }

    public CLAZZ get(Serializable id){
        return(CLAZZ) HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().get(obtainDomainClass(),id);
    }

    public void delete(CLAZZ c){
        HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().delete(c);}

    public void refresh(CLAZZ c)
    {
        HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().refresh(c);
    }

    public void update(CLAZZ c)
    {
        HibernateUtils.getCurrentSession().update(c);
    }



}
```

**LoginServlet.java**

```
package teste.web;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.classic.Session;
import teste.domain.User;
import teste.servicos.LoginService;
import teste.utils.HibernateUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.io.IOException;

public class LoginServlet extends AbstractServlet
{
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginServlet.class);

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        LoginService loginService = new LoginService();


        String username = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");

        logger.info("Username: " + username);
        logger.debug("Password" + password);

        User user = loginService.checkLogin(username,password,null);

        if (user!= null){
            String roles = loginService.returnRole();
            logger.info("Username: " + username);

            if (roles !=null){
                HttpSession session = req.getSession();

                req.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", user);
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                session.setAttribute("roles",roles);

                String encodedURL = resp.encodeRedirectUrl("home.jsp");
                resp.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
            }else {
                HttpSession session = req.getSession();

                req.setAttribute("userLoggedIn", user);
                session.setAttribute("username", username);
                session.setAttribute("roles", "normal");

                String encodedURL = resp.encodeRedirectUrl("home.jsp");
                resp.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
            }
        }else {
            String encodedURL = resp.encodeRedirectUrl("http://localhost:8080/TrabalhoES/login.jsp?wrong_password");
            resp.sendRedirect(encodedURL);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doService(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }
}
```

**LoginService.java**

```
package teste.servicos;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import teste.domain.User;
import teste.domain.UserSession;
import teste.domain.dao.DaoFactory;
import teste.servicepack.security.logic.Permission.Transaction;
import teste.utils.HibernateUtils;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LoginService {

    User user = null;

@Transaction
    public User checkLogin (String username, String password, UserSession session) throws ServletException, IOException{



    List<User> users = ( List<User>) DaoFactory.createUserDao().createCriteria().list();




        for (User value : users){

            if (value.getUsername().equals(username) && value.getPassword().equals(password)){
                System.out.println(session.getCookie());
                user = value;
                session.setUser(value);
                return user;
            }
        }
        return null;



    }

    @Transaction
    public String returnRole(){
        return user.getRoles();
    }
}
```

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
        <property name="show_sql">@hibernate.show.sql@</property>



        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <!--<property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>-->
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.auto_close_session">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</property>
       <!--<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">150</property>
        <property name="hibernate.max_statements">50</property>-->


        <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.CurrentSessionContext</property>-->
        <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.JTASessionContext</property>-->
        <!--<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookup</property>-->
        <!--<property name="current_session_context_class">org.hibernate.context.ThreadLocalSessionContext</property>-->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!--
            <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">3</property>
        -->
        <mapping resource="teste/domain/UserSession.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="teste/domain/Section.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="teste/domain/Page.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="teste/domain/Component.hbm.xml"/>
        <mapping resource="teste/domain/User.hbm.xml"/>
        <!--<mapping resource="teste/domain/Customer.hbm.xml"/>-->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I'm not using Spring, that's why I couldn't find many solutions. Can anyone explain it to me why I'm facing this issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I resolve "org.hibernate.HibernateException: createCriteria is not valid without active transaction" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145935/how-can-i-resolve-org-hibernate-hibernateexception-createcriteria-is-not-valid)

Comment: I saw that post first but when I tried unfortunately didn't work for me